# Simplest way to display API results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, curl

Im kind of new to this and looking to expand pulling API results and displaying them on page, whether it's from a blog resource or content generation.

For example, I want to pull from VirusTotal's API to display returned content. What is the best way to capture that in an input tag and display it in a DIV. And what if it were an option to pull from different API's based on drop down selection?

An example of the API to pull content would be here https://developers.virustotal.com/reference#api-responses under the /file/report section.

Comment: Click on the word Python in that link. They give you the code that answers your question. Now once you get the results you can use javascript among many other techniques to 'display it in a DIV'. Good luck, just keep at it!

Comment: Do you want this web page publicly visible? Or is it just for your own personal use?

Comment: The web page is just for personal use.

Answer (score 0):

To call the data from the API, you need to send a request. However, there is a problem with CORS. Basically, you can't call the website from inside your web browser from a page on your local machine, because your browser blocks the request. The web browser will only allow calls to and from the same server, except for a few exceptions.

There's two ways to approach this.

1. The simplest one is to make a program that calls the API and outputs an HTML file. You can then open that HTML file to read the contents. If you want to update the info, you would need to run that program once again manually. You could easily do this building off the python they provided.
2. The other, little bit more complex way, is where you host a server on your PC. When you go to the webpage on that server, it sends a request to the website, and then provides the latest information. There's tons of frameworks and ways to do this. For an absolute beginner on this subject, ExpressJS is a good start. You can make a hello world program, and once you do that you can figure out how to call the API whenever a page is loaded, and display the results.